# how to make a column that will store sum of all related records from another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables

**episodes**

```
name          views       fk
    ----          -----       ---
    ep 1           234         1----|
                                    + -> 234 + 213
    ep 2           213         1----|


    ep 3           634         2----|
                                    + -> 634 + 295
    ep 4           295         2----|
```

**series**

```
id     name          views
==     ----          -----
1      s 1           sum_of_all_related_views_fields (234+213)
2      s 2           (634+295)
```

there is a relation between `id -> FK == 1` to many

I want to have e column like the above view column what should I do?
all I can think about is views and triggers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join the `series` table on an aggregate query from the `episodes` table:

```sql
SELECT s.*, e.views
FROM   series s
JOIN   (SELECT   fk, SUM(views) AS views
        FROM     episodes
        GROUP BY fk) e on e.fk = s.id
```